# Enabling Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

According to developer doc, below code is added to enable crashlytics.

```
final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(new Crashlytics())
            .debuggable(true)  // Enables Crashlytics debugger
            .build();
    Fabric.with(fabric);
```

My questions are:

1. Shall I add the above code to each activity? or one activity is enough?
2. Shall I change `.debuggable(true)` to `.debuggable(false)` when preparing for signed APK for publishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to initialize Crashlythics, just place `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());` in the `onCreate()` method of the first activity you are displaying to the user

1.- Only call it once, in the first activity

2.- You don't need to set `debugger(true)`, just set it to `false`

Comment: for second question, when to set true and when to set false?

Comment: @AtefFarouk The javadocs says "Enable Logging". I believe this flag could be of use if you wanted to debug the library.